# How to integrate OpenCV 3.1.0 in oculus mobile sdk 1.0.3 sample "VrTemplate" [Android Studio, Win8, GearVR]

Tags: android, opencv, android-studio, oculus, gear-vr

I try to integrate OpenCV into a GearVR project, my endgame being to use the "sepia" filter of an OpenCV sample to see the World in a "sepia" filter (and later other filters) through the GearVR.

Here is my process and my problem:
First I follow "https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/mobilesdk/latest/concepts/mobile-new-apps-intro/" to create a new project copied from VrTemplate (a sample included in the oculus mobile sdk). Running it via build.cmd works, creating the 2 warped green "circles" ready for GearVR on the screen.

Then I open Android Studio and "file-new-import project" and select the build.gradle file in the newly created project (C:\Dev1\ovr_sdk_mobile_1.0.3\VrSamples\Native\VrAndOpenCVApp\Projects\Android\build.gradle), VrAndOpenCVApp being the name of the project I created earlier.

Running it via Android Studio works, too.

Now I want OpenCV 3.1.0 and I follow this tutorial: "https://chmod600blog.wordpress.com/2016/02/22/how-to-add-opencv-3-1-0-to-android-studio/". I have tested it by creating a new app first and the process is easy and works. Now however, I have to get it into the GearVR-ready template app.
After "File-New-Import Module", "File -> Project Structure" selecting "Android" module on the left ("Android" must be the standard name given by the template, rather than "app" when you create your own new app). "Dependencies" tab -> "+" -> "Module Dependency" and choosing openCVLibrary310 which I just added.
Here the error "Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found." appears, which will stay with me until the end. Step 12 of the tutorial and I open "C:\Dev1\ovr_sdk_mobile_1.0.3\VrSamples\Native\VrAndOpenCVApp\Projects\Android\openCVLibrary310\build.gradle" and "C:\Dev1\ovr_sdk_mobile_1.0.3\VrSamples\Native\VrAndOpenCVApp\Projects\Android\build.gradle"
, where I adjust the values of compileSdkVersion, buildToolsVersion, defaultConfig/minSdkVersion and defaultConfig/targetSdkVersion

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }
```

.

After syncing Gradle files the error "Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found." remains. I don't know how to get more info about this Error, googling gave me a few suggestions, but I'm not sure if I applied them incorrectly or if they don't apply to my problem.

I tried:

- changing buildtools, target and compiled sdk version (gradle version used seems 1.5.0 by the gradle wrapper that comes with the oculus mobile sdk)
- linking it to a new app as the tutorial suggests, which worked and was easy. The Project stucture looks different. I have screenshots, but can't post them because my account here is new.

build.gradle of openCVLibrary310 in the template project folder

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
        compileSdkVersion 19
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 19
            targetSdkVersion 19
        }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
```

build.gradle of the template app (ignore buildtools, i'm just testing different ones)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "${rootProject.projectDir}/VrApp.gradle"

dependencies {
  compile project(':VrAppFramework:Projects:AndroidPrebuilt')
  compile project(':VrAppSupport:SystemUtils:Projects:AndroidPrebuilt')
  compile project(':VrAppSupport:VrGUI:Projects:AndroidPrebuilt')
  compile project(':VrAppSupport:VrLocale:Projects:AndroidPrebuilt')
  compile project(':VrAppSupport:VrSound:Projects:AndroidPrebuilt')
  //compile project(':VrSamples:Native:VrAndOpenCVApp:Projects:Android:openCVLibrary310') //same error
  compile project(':openCVLibrary310')
}

android {
  project.archivesBaseName = "VrAndOpenCVApp"

  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.daprlab.VrAndOpenCVApp"
  }

  compileSdkVersion 23
  buildToolsVersion '24.0.0'

  sourceSets {
    main {
      manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
      java.srcDirs = ['../../java']
      jniLibs.srcDir 'libs'
      res.srcDirs = ['../../res']
      assets.srcDirs = ['../../assets']
    }
  }
}
```

settings.gradle of template project

```
rootProject.projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../../../../..')
rootProject.name = "VrAndOpenCVApp"

include ':', \
    'VrApi:Projects:AndroidPrebuilt', \
    'VrAppFramework:Projects:AndroidPrebuilt', \
    'VrAppSupport:VrLocale:Projects:AndroidPrebuilt', \
    'VrAppSupport:VrSound:Projects:AndroidPrebuilt', \
    'VrSamples:Native:VrAndOpenCVApp:Projects:Android', \
    'VrAppSupport:SystemUtils:Projects:AndroidPrebuilt', \
    'VrAppSupport:VrGUI:Projects:AndroidPrebuilt'
include ':openCVLibrary310'
```

settings.gradle in the toplevel

```
rootProject.projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '.')
rootProject.name = "OculusRoot"

include ':VrApi:Projects:AndroidPrebuilt', \
':VrAppFramework:Projects:AndroidPrebuilt', \
':VrAppSupport:SystemUtils:Projects:AndroidPrebuilt', \
':VrAppSupport:VrLocale:Projects:AndroidPrebuilt', \
':VrAppSupport:VrSound:Projects:AndroidPrebuilt', \
':VrAppSupport:VrGUI:Projects:AndroidPrebuilt'

include ':LibOVRKernel:Projects:Android', \
':VrAppFramework:Projects:Android', \
':VrCapture:Projects:Android', \
':VrApi:Impl:Projects:Android', \
':VrApi:Loader:Projects:Android', \
':VrAppSupport:SystemUtils:Projects:Android', \
':VrAppSupport:VrGUI:Projects:Android', \
':VrAppSupport:VrLocale:Projects:Android', \
':VrAppSupport:VrModel:Projects:Android', \
':VrAppSupport:VrSound:Projects:Android'

include ':openCVLibrary310'
```